# v.surf.idw raster file conversion into a vector with same colours style

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, color-ramp, vectorization

Is it possible to convert from raster to vector the raster file resulting from grass interpolation algorithm "v.surf.idw" coloured with the quantile method and maintain such colours in the vector file in QGIS.

Comment: See r.to.vect GRASS command.

Comment: In addition, r.colors and v.colors can transfer color tables from another map.